# SimpleDateFormat sets current day for parsed date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Is there any way to use the following simpleDateFormat:

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
```

and when invoking:

```
simpleDateFormat.parse("12:32:21 JST");
```

to return current date on the Date object?

For these example, it will return:

```
Thu Jan 01 05:32:21 EET 1970
```

and not:

```
<<today>> 05:32:21 EET <<currentYear>>
```

as I need.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` does not support default dates, or in other words: 1970-01-01 is the only fixed default date for this formatter. If you wish more flexibility then you could use `DateTimeFormatter` in Java-8.

Answer (score 2):

No, `SimpleDateFormat` needs explicity the date in the input string. If you're using Java 8, you can go with a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDate.now().atTime(5, 32, 21);
```

If you want to include a time-zone, you can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Answer (score 1):

Construct another `SimpleDateFormat` to print today's date:

```
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").print(new Date());
```

(Be careful here: you might want to set the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat`, as "today" is different in different time zones).

Update the date format to include year, month and day:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z");
```

And then prepend the date string with the date you want:

```
simpleDateFormat.parse(today + " " + "12:32:21 JST");
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution using flexible default values (today instead of 1970-01-01) would be in **Java-8** with the new built-in date-time-library located in package `java.time`:

```
String input = "12:32:21 JST";
String pattern = "HH:mm:ss z";

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, today.getYear())
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, today.getMonthValue()).parseDefaulting(
        ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH,
        today.getDayOfMonth()
    ).appendPattern(pattern).toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
System.out.println(zdt); // 2016-12-23T12:32:21+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
```

However, I still see a small bug related to the fact that this code makes a hardwired assumption about the used zone BEFORE parsing the real zone so please handle with care. Keep in mind that the current date depends on the zone. But maybe you only need to handle a scenario where just the Japan time is used by users.

**Hint: You can also parse in two steps.** First step with any kind of fixed default date in order to get the zone information of the text to be parsed. And then you can use this zone information for suggested solution above. An awkward but safe procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you want to change only the year and the day

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatHour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = simpleDateFormatHour.parse("12:32:21 JST");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
date = calendar.getTime();
```